# Can select commands edit a sql database in anyway?

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way in which select commands alter a sqlite database? I would assume not, but don't want to rely on that assumption. (the specific concern i had in mind was if e.g. querying the database for example creates indexes or similar for quicker retrieval in subsequent times, hence causing the sql files to change)

Asking, because i want to cache some values calculated from a sql file, and only update these values if there has been an edit to the sql file [specifically if the number of bytes file size has changed, which would indicate the sql database has changed. The specific calculations are quite computations intensive, so don't want to repeat unless neaded].

Comment: Consider using database triggers to monitor insert/update/delete on the relevant tables and then based on that initiate the calculations

Comment: Updating the database won't change the size most likely. Maybe look at the timestamp, but triggers are definitely the way to go as NicoE said.

Comment: @topshot - thanks - yeh, file-size probably was a poor choice now i think about it. will also consider triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT statements cannot modify the database.

SQLite sometimes needs to store temporary indexes or intermediate results, but such data goes into the temporary database, not into the actual database file.

Anyway, to find out whether a database file has changed, check the [file change counter](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#file_change_counter).